# How can i change style of dynamically created input field?

Tags: css, styles, dynamically-generated

The element code is look like this

```
<select id="TsSection_ts_subjectid" name="TsSection[ts_subjectid][]">
<select id="TsSection_ts_subjectid" name="TsSection[ts_subjectid][]">
<select id="TsSection_ts_subjectid" name="TsSection[ts_subjectid][]">
```

i want to change border of 2nd element?

Comment: Element `ids` must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element must have a unique `id`, I'd suggest you change them to classes instead:

```
<select class="TsSection_ts_subjectid" name="TsSection[ts_subjectid][]">
```

Then, you can use the [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-child) selector to target the 2nd element:

```
select.TsSection_ts_subjectid:nth-child(2) {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ak3SV/)